# Is this an NP-Complete problem? (unweighted & undirected graph)

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, np-complete

G is an **unweighted, undirected** graph.
Then, I cannot prove that [deciding whether G has a path of length greater than k] is NP-Complete.

How can I show whether the algorithm is NP-complete or not?

Comment: The easiest way to prove a problem is NP complete is usually to show that you can use it to solve a different NP-complete problem with only polynomial many questions and polynomialy many extra steps. Really that only shows the problem is NP-hard but this problem is obviously in NP so if it's NP-hard it's NP-complete

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem

Answer (score 2):

Let $G$ be your graph, and let it have $n$ vertices.

[The Hamiltonian path problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem) is NP-complete. $G$ has a Hamiltionian path if and only if its longest path has length $n - 1$. Thus, the decision problem you described must be NP-complete.

Answer (score 2):

This problem can be shown to NP-hard by reducing the longest path problem to it. It's not hard to do so maybe you want to give it a try first before I give you the reduction.